# How to cast char array to int at non-aligned position?

Tags: c++, c, alignment, reinterpret-cast, pointer-arithmetic

Is there a way in C/C++ to cast a char array to an int at any position?

I tried the following, bit it automatically aligns to the nearest 32 bits (on a 32 bit architecture) if I try to use pointer arithmetic with non-const offsets:

```
unsigned char data[8];
data[0] = 0; data[1] = 1; ... data[7] = 7;
int32_t p = 3;
int32_t d1 = *((int*)(data+3));  // = 0x03040506  CORRECT
int32_t d2 = *((int*)(data+p));  // = 0x00010203  WRONG
```

Update:

- As stated in the comments the input comes in tuples of 3 and I cannot
  change that.
- I want to convert 3 values to an int for further
  processing and this conversion should be as fast as possible.
- The
  solution does not have to be cross platform. I am working with a very
  specific compiler and processor, so it can be assumed that it is a 32
  bit architecture with big endian.
- The lowest byte of the result does not matter to me (see above).

My main questions at the moment are: Why has d1 the correct value but d2 does not? Is this also true for other compilers? Can this behavior be changed?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: The comments devolved. They were deleted. If you have an answer, please post it.  Have a better way? Post it as an answer!  Take a chance.

Comment: Since it does not seem to be possible I solved it partly by working with 4 pixels at a time to avoid alignment problems.

Comment: This did not work either... The compiler seems to align at 2^N borders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do that in a portable way.

The behaviour encountered when attempting a cast from `char*` to `int*` is *undefined* in both C and C++ (possibly for the very reasons that you've spotted: `int`s are possibly aligned on 4 byte boundaries and `data` is, of course, contiguous.)

(The fact that `data+3` works but `data+p` doesn't is possibly due to to compile time vs. runtime evaluation.)

Also note that the signed-ness of `char` is not specified in either C or C++ so you should use `signed char` or `unsigned char` if you're writing code like this.

Your best bet is to use bitwise shift operators (`>>` and `<<`) and logical `|` and `&` to absorb `char` values into an `int`. Also consider using `int32_t`in case you build to targets with 16 or 64 bit `int`s.

Comment: And why does it work with const values? I assume that would be compiler dependent if it works or not?

Comment: const values? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In my example (at least with my compiler) d1 has the correct value but d2 has not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way, converting a pointer to a wrongly aligned one is undefined.

You can use `memcpy` to copy the `char` array into an `int32_t`.

```
int32_t d = 0;
memcpy(&d, data+3, 4); // assuming sizeof(int) is 4
```

Most compilers have built-in functions for `memcpy` with a constant size argument, so it's likely that this won't produce any runtime overhead.

Even though a cast like you've shown is allowed for correctly aligned pointers, dereferencing such a pointer is a violation of strict aliasing. An object with an effective type of `char[]` must not be accessed through an lvalue of type `int`.

In general, type-punning is endianness-dependent, and converting a `char` array representing RGB colours is probably easier to do in an endianness-agnostic way, something like

```
int32_t d = (int32_t)data[2] << 16 | (int32_t)data[1] << 8 | data[0];
```

Comment: Not a good idea. C does not require `char` to be unsigned. If `char` is signed, the conversion to `int32_t` will sign-extend, potentially setting all the most significant bits in `d` with the `|`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the input. That is given in my case. I know I could do it with shifting and so on, but that is much slower and this part is rather performance critical. I hoped there would be a direct way which only needs roughly one instruction instead of several, since the data already is in the correct order in memory...

Comment: @EOF: `data` is `unsigned char` in the question.

Comment: @EOF: I am using unsigned char so that would not be a problem

Comment: @Karsten: Compilers usually have built-ins for `memcpy`-ing a constant amount of bytes, that shouldn't be any overhead.

Comment: I've forgot that you want an offset from the array, so the union trick to align doesn't work anyway (`data+3` needs to be `int`-aligned here); I'll edit this out, I think.

Comment: @mafso: I see. However, you really don't need the union if you `memcpy()`. `char` aliases `int`, you can `memcpy()` directly to an `int`.

Comment: @Karsten: Your "one instruction to copy" goal may not work anyway for unaligned access (especially if you have a platform were unaligned access is a problem in the first place).

Comment: @Karsten: Are you *sure* shifting is too slow?

Comment: @Bathsheba: I did some profiling and with -O2 shifting actually twice as slow as direct access/conversion which does not work unfortunately. `memcpy` is only slightly faster than shifting. But I assume it is the best I can get :(

Comment: @Karsten: Well, if you're willing to accept a program that "[...]does not work unfortunately", I can give you one that takes no time to run at all. Why do you compare a working program's runtime with a non-working one's?

Comment: @EOF: I did this comparison, because I hoped it would somehow be possible to achieve this and I was just not doing it the right way, because it worked with a constant offset.

Comment: @Karsten: Does it work with a constant offset if the contents of `data` are unknown to the compiler? And for your real use-case: Is the offset constant?